Container size scaling issue with large images on import
I'm encountering an issue with Cropper.js where importing large images causes the container of the cropper to expand disproportionately. Specifically, when I import a large image into Cropper.js, the container size increases significantly, affecting the user experience. However, this problem does not occur when importing smaller images.
To elaborate, I'm utilizing Cropper.js to allow users to crop images within a defined container on a web application. Unfortunately, when importing large images, the container size expands excessively, making it challenging for users to effectively manage the cropping area.
Despite thoroughly reviewing the Cropper.js documentation and searching for similar issues online, I have not found a solution specific to this problem.
Could someone please provide insights or suggestions on how to address this issue? Is there a method to ensure that the container of the cropper remains a consistent size regardless of the dimensions of the imported image?

Provide a minimum of code that can be reasoned about

you need to provide fixed aspect ratio for the container.
